# Derivative of $\log \vert C'\Sigma^{-1}C \vert$

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product

I am trying to compute the derivative of $F(X)=\log \vert C'\Sigma^{-1}C \vert$, where $C = C(X) = (J_1 + J_2 \otimes X)$. All matrices are real, $\Sigma$ is positive definite, $C$ is invertible for every $X$. Here's where I get stuck:

I compute the differential to be

\begin{align}
dF &=\mathrm{tr} \left[(C'\Sigma^{-1}C)^{-1}(C'\Sigma^{-1} dC + (dC)'\Sigma^{-1}C)\right] \\
&= 2\mathrm{tr} \left[(C'\Sigma^{-1}C)^{-1}(C'\Sigma^{-1}) dC \right] \\
&= 2\mathrm{tr} \left[(C'\Sigma^{-1}C)^{-1}(C'\Sigma^{-1}) (J_2 \otimes dX) \right],
\end{align}

but **where do I go from here**? I can't see how to isolate $dX$ on the right hand side. Maybe there is another path I should be taking. Or maybe there is a rule to read the derivative directly from this form of differential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing your differential in terms of the [Frobenius Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) yields
$$\eqalign{
  df &= 2\Sigma^{-1}C(C^T\Sigma^{-1}C)^{-1} : J_2\otimes dX \cr
     &= M : J_2\otimes dX \cr
}$$
Assume that we can find a Kronecker Product Decomposition for the matrix on the LHS,  i.e.
$$\eqalign{
  M &= A\otimes B \cr
}$$
where the shape of A is similar to J, and B to X.

Now apply the Kronecker-Frobenius mixed product rule 
$$\eqalign{
 df &= (A\otimes B):(J_2\otimes dX) \cr
    &= (A:J_2) \otimes (B:dX)  \cr
    &= (A:J_2)B:dX  \cr
}$$
Since $df=\big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}:dX\big),\,$ the gradient must be
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= (J_2:A)\,B \cr
}$$
If you cannot find a single Kronecker product that equals M, you can always find a sum of such products
$$\eqalign{
  M &= \sum_k A_k\otimes B_k \cr
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= \sum_k (J_2:A_k)\,B_k \cr
}$$